# trying to get current location on my google-map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get my current location on google map but it's giving me a blank map.

this is my fragment

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLng userLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationManager mLocationManager;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    userLocation = new LatLng(location.getAltitude(), location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, "found you...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MarkerOptions markerOptions= new MarkerOptions();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 10));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("you are here"));
  }


  @Override
  public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

  }
}
```

then that's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBuSE2O0siczDYt3oh3FVUgcO_MZs4-8FQ" />

<!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.liadiluz.finalproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".services.MyIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps2"></activity>
</application>
```

and that's the layout file

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.liadiluz.finalproject.Activities.MapsActivity" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: any errors in your Logcat? Please post your Logcat too..

Comment: my logical doesn't show errors

Comment: please post your Logcat..

Comment: Your code looks ok did you check whether you have internet connectivity or not because you should be able to see the map.
And secondly please check whether you have entered the correct key or not.