# Background color problems with AppCombatActivity on Android

Tags: android, layout, background

I recently switched all my activities from `ActionBarActivity` to the more recent `AppCompatActivity`, and I noticed some strange rendering problems on the login page:

[image]

It is not too visible, but there is discoloration on the bottom after the last widget.  Also, on my phone there is discoloration on the right side of the activity.  Here is the structure of the layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- content here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Has anyone had experience with this sort of background problem with `AppCombatActivity`?

**Update:**

The accepted answer's solution fixed the problem on the bottom of the activity.  With regard to the discoloration on the right side of the activity, it turns this is happening for *every* app on my phone.  It looks like my Samsung phone's display is getting old, and perhaps I should think about replacing it.

Comment: yesterday I've got -2 on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312112/trying-to-get-current-location-on-my-google-map/44312181) and after that person asking question commented that my ans resolved his/her problem, without +1 and accepting. life... :)

Comment: have you try move android:background="@color/white" from LinearLayout to the ScrollView?

Comment: @OctavianoPutra That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fillViewport` set for `ScrollView` instead of `fitsSystemWindows`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />
</ScrollView>
```

[A useful article is here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).

Comment: This didn't fix it, but I'll keep this in mind in case the problem has multiple causes.  The _really_ bizarre thing is that the discoloration on the left does not show up in the screen capture.  In other words, my own Android phone doesn't see it, every though my eyes do.  Many the display has a problem.

Comment: on screenshot I see discoloration just below "forgot password" and I'm pretty shure that `fillViewport` should fix it... maybe some Java lines causes some other problems. try to set some color (black?) for `ScrollView` and check that this light-gray is in fact default color of `ScrollView`. you may also turn on "draw bounds" option under Developer settings on device. edit: try with `wrap_content` for `LinearLayout` height

Comment: Adding `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` fixed the problem on the bottom.  The issue on the left hand side is still there.  Strange, it doesn't appear in landscape mode.  I will keep an eye on this over the next few days and try to see if other activities now also have this problem +1

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the background color on the inner LinearLayout? This will cause overdraw problems. Set the background color in your theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Or in your Activity's onCreate:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.white);
```

The grey discoloration is because there is a grey window background for Activity in the default theme, and you set a white background color in the LinearLayout, but the LinearLayout height is not same as the Window height.

Comment: How do you explain that there is a column on the right side which is discolored (not grey)?

Comment: About window backgrond overdraw see : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

Comment: The other answer fixed the problem on the bottom, but not on the sides.  It appears my phone's display may have a problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen set the background color to red color, and tack a screenshot.

Comment: No, your hypothesis doesn't explain what is happening, so I won't do this.